# Fitting in this awk statement

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I have a `bash` script I am working on that calls another `awk` script. This is the line of code:

`awk -f /home/rkahil/BMS/parse.awk $filename.tmp > $filename | /..,[A-Z][A-Z]/ $filename`

I know syntactically this is worng, but I need this following regex expression `/..,[A-Z][A-Z]/ $filename` is syntactically wrong but I need to fit this in to this statement and am not quite sure how to. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you need to add the last regex to the awk script without modifying the awk script. You need to edit your question and provide a clear statement of your requirements. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

This may be a GNU awk feature, but you can provide multiple `-f` options that concatenates all the named awk script into one. Thus:

```
awk -f /home/rkahil/BMS/parse.awk \
    -f <(echo 'FILENAME ~ /..,[A-Z][A-Z]/') \
    $filename.tmp > $filename
```

Demo:

```
$ cat foo.awk
/foo/ {print}
$ cat bar.awk 
/bar/ {print}
$ awk -f foo.awk -f bar.awk -f <(echo '/baz/ {print}') <<END
blah
foo
hello
world 
var bar car
1234
ab cbazdef
bye
END
```

```
foo
var bar car
ab cbazdef
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include this condition in your awk script:

```
awk 'FILENAME ~ /..,[A-Z][A-Z]/{...}' "$filename"
```

Comment: It did, however I need to find a place to put it in the awk script rather than the bash script. Thanks much!

Comment: But `FILENAME ~ /..,[A-Z][A-Z]/` is indeed the awk code not BASH code.

Comment: Sorry let me rephrase. I need to use the regex in my awk script that I have because the bash is not giving me the desired result.

Comment: You can just start your awk script with `!(FILENAME ~ /..,[A-Z][A-Z])/{exit}`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you mean:

```
awk -f /home/rkahil/BMS/parse.awk "$filename.tmp" | grep '..,[A-Z][A-Z]' > "$filename"
```

? It's not entirely clear what you mean, but the above will perform the awk script without modification, and then filter the output on the given regular expression, finally writing the result to the original file.